# Is is safe to have rainwater recycling tank near the bedroom windows?

Tags: water, safety, recycling

Is it safe to sleep near a rainwater recycling tank? Is bacteria can developed and flow into the bedroom when sleeping with the window open?

[image: Water tank.]

[image: Configuration: bedroom, bed and water tank.]

Comment: There would be no issue if it were a closed 55 gallon drum that light can't get through.  Standing water is never a good idea, no matter where it is.  There are good resources on how to make a proper rain barrel if you search for them.  This setup just looks like a waste of a good trash can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standing stagnant water can harbor legionnaire's disease, be a mosquito breeding ground, etc. And as @mike says, regional hazards vary, check with your local health authority, what works here in Oregon might not work for example, in Florida, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the biggest risks from these type of tanks is an increase in mosquitos.   The very young mosquitos that emerge from the water may be small enough to get through some screens or seals.

Comment: The Mosquitoes that carry West Nile are tiny, and hatch their larva in mud. Which means over-watered lawns, eave troughs with sediment and moist ditches are a prime breeding ground for them. Dengue, Malaria, Yellow Fever, different types of encephalitis depending on the continent or island group are carried by the larger mosquitoes that would find an open rain barrel the ideal environment.